# How to get array data in form's value field in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am passing a variable with form view to get values from database in form.

```
public function getGeneralSettings()
    {

        $generalsetting = DB::table('generalsettings')
                ->where('id', '=', 1)
                ->get();
        return view('backend.generalsettings.add-general')->with('general', $generalsetting);
    }
```

What i am getting is :

```
[{"id":1,"sitename":"eqwe","tagline":"ewqewq","logo":"1492084338.jpg","firstemail":"qwewq","secondemail":"ewqewq","firstphone":21321,"secondphone":32132,"address":"
dassa<\/p>","facebook":"dqw","twitter":"q","linkedin":"q","google":"q","youtube":"q","instagram":null,"reddit":"q","rss":"q","created_at":"2017-04-13 11:52:18","updated_at":"2017-04-13 11:52:18"}]
```

I wana show these values in my form fields.

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sitename">Site Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="sitename" name="sitename" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Site name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="tagline">Tagline</label>
                        <input type="text" id="tagline" name="tagline" placeholder="Tagline" value="" class="form-control">
                    </div>
```

How to call them in particular value field. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use `{{}}`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sitename">Site Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="sitename" name="sitename" class="form-control" value="{{$general->sitename}}" placeholder="Site name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="tagline">Tagline</label>
    <input type="text" id="tagline" name="tagline" placeholder="Tagline" value="{{$general->tagline}}" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Also use `first()` instead of `get()` to get single object

Comment: Thank u.. I tried the value="{{$general->sitename}}" before.. bt i was getting error. Main issue was first(); Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your controller code to

```
public function getGeneralSettings()
{

    $generalsetting = DB::table('generalsettings')
            ->where('id', '=', 1)
            ->first();
    return view('backend.generalsettings.add-general')->with('general', $generalsetting);
}
```

Whenever you want to retrieve a single row result, use `first()` instead of `get()`, `get()` is used for getting multiple records.